# Can't upgrade or remove pip package "altgraph" on MacOs(Mojave)

Tags: python, macos, pip, pycharm, pyinstaller

I want to install PyInstaller package through pip, So I typed "pip install pyinstaller", but it occur errors

[image]

and I was trying to upgrade the alt graph to latest version.. but it occur same errors

how can I install the PyInstaller or how can I upgrade the package altgraph ?

Therefore, even I can't delete altgraph using

```
rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/.../altgraph
```

What I did in terminal

```
pip install pyinstall - not working
pip install --upgrade altgraph - not working
pip uninstall altgraph - not working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from

http://marcelog.github.io/articles/mac_osx_python_pip_install_operation_not_permitted.html

install package under a user

`pip install <package> --user`